# How do I copy a row into each of the following tab after it based on one column response?

Tags: google-sheets, copy-data

example pic: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxMUF.png)

In Google Sheets, I want to take the data from the 1st tab and transfer only the rows that show monthly expenses to the following tabs.
So based on the picture I attached, on the January tab I want the row with Sam/$75/monthly and John/$100/monthly to be copied to the next tabs (Feb, Mar, and the rest of the months when I add them).  And then from the February tab, I want to copy the Sam/$75/monthly and John/$100/monthly rows as well as the Mary/$150/monthly row.

Here's the example spreadsheet I was using.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uXoNJh6BH4an3oFD5V-naQo1lG7n5xxxcCCj0noBsH8/edit?usp=sharing

I know I can use "=Sheet1! A1" but the problem with that one is I want it to figure out the rows I want automatically based on the column label "frequency of expenses."

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to copy the rows containing the text "monthly" in column C (Expense Frequency) from sheet number 1 to all other sheets. Additionally, you want to copy the rows containing the text "Mary" in column A (Name), the number 150 in column B (Expenses), and the text "monthly" in column C (Expense Frequency) from the sheet named Feb to all other sheets except sheet named Jan.
Is everything okay?

Comment: Yes, I want to copy the rows containing the text "monthly" in column C from sheet #1 to sheet #2, sheet #3, sheet #4, and so on. Then any new rows added to sheet #2 containing the text "monthly" in column C to sheet #3, sheet #4, and so on.  Then any new rows added to sheet #3 containing the text "monthly" in column C to sheet #4, and each sheet added. I added some more tabs to my example spreadsheet hoping that helps.  I plan to have 12 tabs (1 for each month) when I create the full file.

Comment: From the statement of the problem, it is not clear at what point you intend to run the script. It can be assumed that in some cases it is possible to create duplicates. How then to distinguish one identical record from another? It will be unclear whether this is a duplicate or whether these are different namesake people.